# If I'm changing a Python global variable's data from a function, it throws error. (It works fine if not passing any arguments)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global-variables

On python 3.6,

Code 1:

```
x="glob"
def reg(x):
    print(x)
    x="loc"
    print(x)
reg(x)
```

Output:

glob
loc

Code 2:

```
x="glob"
def reg():
    print(x)
    x="loc"
    print(x)
reg()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\Python\abc.py", line 6, in <module>
    reg()
  File "D:\Projects\Python\abc.py", line 3, in reg
    print(x)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

**Why does this happen?**
What's the difference if I'm not passing a global variable to a function??
Shouldn't it be accessible to all the functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Answer (score 0):

You can visit https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html. There is an example about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should user global.

**Code 2**

```
x="glob"
def reg():
    global x
    print(x)
    x="loc"
    print(x)
reg()
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable scope of inside and outside of function is different.
Inside of function definition, it has own scope when you assign new variables.
If you intend to *reassign* global variable, you should use `global` statement.

```py
global x
```

This statement mean

> When I assign variable in this function scope, it is not function scope but global scope

Please note that it is only about **assigning**, so you don't need to `global` statement to **use** global variables.
In addition, in most case, *reassigning* global variable is not a good idea, Since it makes your code complicated. There are so many alternatives of it.
But still you want to do this, you can:

```py
x = "glob"
def reg():
    global x

    print(x)
    x = "loc"
    print(x)
reg()
```

And about the first example,
Reassigning argument in function does not affect outside of function.